# Run Specflow Feature file with Nunit Console from 3.4 and above

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow, nunit-console

I need to run my Speflow feature file with Nunit 3.6 console. Just need to know how can i run specific feature? As fixure is not supported anymore so just need to know what else can be used? Tried --test = but no luck.

I've tried below command line

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "C:\jenkins\workspace\Nunit_ME_Test\Automation\Automation.csproj"


C:\nunit\nunit3.7.0\nunit3-console.exe C:\jenkins\workspace\Nunit_ME_Test\Automation\bin\Debug\Automation.dll --test=ME_NTJ_Include
```

I have used -test=ME_NTJ_Include where "ME_NTJ_Include" is the feature file .I'm sure something is not right , can any one please help to resolve this .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To learn exactly how SpecFlow is naming your tests at different levels, simply run all of them and examine the XML result file. The name you find there for FullName is what you would have to use with the `--test` option. Most likely, you are simply issing the namespace in which the fixture is defined.

For more flexibility, use the `--where` option. That would allow you to write, for example `--where test=~ME_NTJ_INCLUDE` for a partial match of the name.